# ADFS only allows local browsers and Safari on one Mac to access the verification webpage

Tags: iis, single-sign-on, adfs

So I've setup a Windows 2012 R2 box with AD DS, SQL Server, and AD FS so one of our developers can test out SSO.

The problem is, the test webpage, https:///adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon, only works locally on the server or on Safari on my Mac, where I was RDP'ing into the server from. Firefox and Chrome don't work on my Mac, nor does any browser on any other computer, giving a 503 error every time. That would seem to suggest that something wasn't setup correctly, but it's confusing because it works locally and it works from Safari on my Mac. I did add some IP restrictions in the firewall on the server, but I'm on one of the allowed IPs.

I didn't set AD DS to be a DNS, thinking that wasn't necessary. I'm almost to the point of removing AD FS from the server and re-adding it. I did search around to try and find an answer, but couldn't find anything that seemed to match this specific case.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Er, I think the problem may be the self-signed security certificate. Will post if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed the self-signed security certificate. We added an exception for that and it worked like a charm. Feeling dumb.